# How to strip/remove row number from variable in python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, row

I get the follow output:

`\n35760    08/07/2015 04:56\n35761    08/07/2015 04:57\n35762    08/07/2015 04:58\n35763    08/07/2015 04:59\ndtype: object' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'`

The offending code is:

`timestr = datetime.strptime ( str(datex+" "+timex) , "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`

datex and timex are from a csv file via read_csv function.

Basically, I'm trying to get datetime to use a column in a CSV file as a source reference via strptime.  I don't know if this is even possible.  But it seems so since I get the correct output, except for the fact that the row number is passed to the module.  (I hope I explained that right.  Yes, I'm a newb, if you couldn't tell.)

So, how do I reference datex and timex without the row number?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the section that is `\n#####` after the times?

Comment: You should show us an example of the csv and complete code, how you are reading in data.

Comment: "Are you trying to remove the section that is \n##### after the times?"                                                                                                          Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot provide a direct solution, because you don't provide enough information. I suggest you a way to find the problem:

Surround your code line with a `try` to see the possible offending data line. Here, I'm supposing you are getting/reading lines of data and the data on line 35764 do not have the same format other lines have:

```
try:
    timestr = datetime.strptime ( str(datex+" "+timex) , "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
except:
    print('Data giving error: {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(type(datex), type(timex), datex, timex)
    raise
```

You can investigate the output to see if data is in the right format and decide what to do next.

Comment: Hmm... I know what is the offending data.  The row number \nXXXXX.